# Saving array in property settings returns last object only

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an array of labels and I want to save the the text of this labels so that when the form is loaded the same information is loaded in the same labels

This code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.label = lblArray[i].Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Keeps on overriding the last object as the property is not an array its self. Is there away of making the `Properties.Settings.Default.label` an array so the data is saved and then loaded correctly?

UPDATE

RE: (the given answer below)

TO Load Again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countHeadWaiters; ++i)
           {
               lblHeadWaiterHours[i].Text = Properties.Settings.Default.label[i];
           }
```

but does not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you iterate through your array and on each iteration override previous value stored at `Properties.Settings.Default.label` here:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.label = lblArray[i].Text;
```

you can join values and write it into `Settings`. This is not the best solution and may not work if you happens to have separator in text, but will work for simple scenarious.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.label = string.Joint(Environment.NewLine, lblArray.Select(l => l.Text));
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

you should probably name you setting like `labelsText`

or you can change your `label` setting to `StringCollection`, so that you can

```
 var strings = new StringCollection();

 lblArray.Select(l => l.Text).ToList().ForEach(text => strings.Add(text));

 Properties.Settings.Default.label = strings;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: I understand this but how do I prevent this. I have tried feeding a whole array to it but it complains, it cannot convert a string[] to string

Comment: @aKola if you want to store array as a string you need to join it. Do you have multiple lines in labels?

Comment: No I have a single line of text on each label which I want to reload again. The text is different for each label and I want the same state to be reloaded

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default.label = strings; it keeps saying Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection' to 'string'

Comment: @aKole Have you changed it's type to `StringCollection` in designer?

Comment: Ah ok I have fixed it, small mistake, your code has no error so to load it I need the same code but reversed right?

Comment: @aKola could you please explain what do you mean by that?

Comment: See my update above.. however this does not return any values when the form is loaded